# Draggable div with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#content").draggable();
    });
</script>
<div id="draggable"></div>
```

the html code in draggable is dynamically added and changed with different widths

my issue is when the html components in draggable are changed to be larger than they used to be the componets just overlap outside of the div.

How can i make the background on draggable resizable so when the contents are changed the background also changes?

Comment: Grab the new size dimensions and resize the image. You should provide an example and an attempt to help better understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

With a background color I see no problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogpwYd

JS:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
setInterval(function(){$('#draggable').append('blalba<br>')}, 1000)
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable">bla</div>
<p>
    ajkdfkladjfkl;asj
    afjklasdklfja
    aksdlfas;ldfjk
</p>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#draggable {
  background-color: green
}
```

But you could remove and then readd the background every time to size changes with jQuery `$(#...).css("background-color", "")`

Comment: My issue isn't in the height of the div. If the dynamic elements have a larger width that is where the problem occurs.